# Trapezoid and isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I have got a problem which I have to solve for my practive for an exam. Hope you can help me.

> An isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$ with the parallel sides $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ is given. The incircle of $\triangle BCD$ touches $\overline{CD}$ in the point $P$. The line perpendicular to $\overline{CD}$ at $P$ meets the bisector of $\angle DAC$ at $F$. The circumcircle of $ \triangle ACF$ cuts $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ at $C$ and $G$.
>
> Show that $\triangle AFG$ is isosceles.

Thank you.

Comment: I am really starting to like these geometry problems :)

Comment: So $G$ is $AF\cap CD$? In such a way, how can $AFG$ be possibly isosceles?

Comment: No. The perimeter of ACF cuts the straight CD and the point which is different of C is G.

Comment: @grok: Perhaps you mean *the circumcircle* of $\triangle ACF$, rather than *the perimeter*. (My GeoGebra sketch seems to show that point $G$ defined in this way makes an isosceles $\triangle AFG$.)

Comment: @Blue yes I mean the circumcircle but I thought that the perimeter is a synonym. I know that GeoGebra shows it but I have to prove it ;). And I need help because I don't know how I have to solve it.

Comment: @grok: "perimeter" is the total length of a triangle's segments. It is definitely *not* a synonym for "circumcircle". (At least, not in English.) If you're heading into an exam, you'll want to keep that in mind. :)  I mentioned the GeoGebra sketch not as proof of the result, but as evidence for my suggested clarification of terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be the incenter of $\triangle ACD$, let $E$ be the incenter of $\triangle BCD$, and let $Q$ be the foot of the altitude from $I$ to $CD$. Since $CP=QD$ by symmetry, it follows that $F$ is in fact the $A$-excenter of $\triangle ACD$. Then it follows that:
$$\begin{align*}\angle CFE&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle FCD\\&=\frac{\angle ACD}{2}\\&=\frac{\angle ACD}{2}\\&=\frac{\angle BDC}{2} \\&=\angle EDC \end{align*}$$
Therefore $CEDF$ is cyclic. Finally, a second angle chase gives:
$$\begin{align*}\angle FAG&=\angle FCG\\&=\angle FCD\\&=\angle FED\\&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle EDC\\&=\frac{\pi}{2}+\angle EDC-\angle BDC\\&=\pi-\angle FED-\angle BDC\\&=\pi-\angle DCF-\angle ACD\\&=\pi-\angle ACF\\&=\angle AGF\end{align*}$$
And so $\triangle AFG$ is isosceles with $\overline{AF}=\overline{FG}$ as required.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick solution. But which point in your answer is the point E? ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! E is the incenter of $\triangle BCD$. I will edit.